# Parameter.addwithvalue function error

Tags: c#, sql, string, object, ado.net

```
    public static bool dataMatch(string data, string tableName, string column)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection(CnnStr);//connection string has been applied to CnnStr


        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [@tableName] WHERE [@column]=[@data]";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@tableName",tableName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column", (column as Object).ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", (data as Object).ToString());

        cmd.Connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            dr.Close();
            cmd.Connection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        dr.Close();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        return false;
    }
```

HELLO

the error i get is:

> SqlException was unhandled by user code invalid object name @tableName

i think the problem is that the args of 2nd parameter of the AddWithValue funcs are strings, and they have to be object type, so i tried to convert the 2nd string parameters of the addwithvalue func to Object or object but get the same errors

Comment: This is not going to work with Command.Parameters. Rather you should create a Query your own and set that string to Command.Text property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't parameterized your column names or table names.

You only parameterize your **values**. That's why you can't use `@tableName` and `@column` as a parameter. You can fix them specifying the table name and column name as part of the SQL.

Your code  is a valid syntax for C#, but it is not a valid SQL.

It is a poor solution but if you *really* want to use them, take a look at [*dynamic SQL.*](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` as well.

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CnnStr))
using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + column.ToString() + "=@data";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@data", data.ToString());
    using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. i event tried  --- cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ["+tableName+"] WHERE ["+column+"]=[@data]"; ---- but i get the same error for @data

Comment: May i know what is the best way to do it? (along with parameters of tableName, column, and data)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you do not need brackets around '@data'. By adding brackets, Sql Server is interpreting it as a column name, and so you will get the same error.

Comment: @user3215839 AFAIK, best way to use them as a part of SQL as I showed in my example. You can't parameterize your column name of table names. Sometimes, you just need to changing your strategy is the best way.

Answer (score -1):

You can acheive this by the following  method.

```
 public static bool dataMatch(string data, string tableName, string column)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection(CnnStr);//connection string has been applied to CnnStr


        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM '"+tableName+"' WHERE [@column]=[@data]";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column", (column as Object).ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", (data as Object).ToString());

        cmd.Connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            dr.Close();
            cmd.Connection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        dr.Close();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        return false;
    }
```

Concatenate table name in the query instead of passing as parmater.

Comment: There are two errors:  1. don't put table name in quotes, 2. you'd need to make the column dynamic too.